# Check column size + Alter table or Alter table directly

Tags: performance, t-sql, resize

We have a process that gets a list of table columns and the sizes(varchar type) each should have and modifies them to ensure it has the defined size.

In the actual implementation we directly perform an alter table to each column in the list...

Would it run faster if we check first if the column size is different to the correct size and only then doing the alter table?

Statistically there are 4000 or so table columns to check and 20 columns need correction at most...

Comment: the tables columns and their sizes are stored in a specific table and we loop throught it

Comment: If the columns and their sizes can be accessed as a single row set, it should be trivial to perform a query on the row set and filter out columns that don't need changing. *Then* you would proceed looping through the remaining rows like you do now. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we implemented the check before the alter table, having a low % of cases where it was necesary to perform the alter command the proccess runs notably faster

Answer (score 2):

Edit: To reflect comments:

What's faster depends on how costly the operation to amend the column is together with how many columns in a table that need changing. For example altering one column of nulls is not very expense. But if you have a lot of data you and lots of columns in the table it might be better to do a table to new table copy. Deciding this depending on the metrics of your database and there isn't always a right and wrong anseer.

You could possibly create some dynamic sql to create the sql that alters the length on columns that aren't the right size. This has got to be the fastest way.

something like:

```
SELECT  
     'some decision logic...' -- substitute values as needed 
FROM 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
        ISNULL(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 5) <> 5 
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'NVARCHAR'
```

And you could add in the metrics you want to account for, table size, data size number of columns (group by) etc.

The Sql Server already stores all this metadata and you can just query it. Seems wrong to duplicate this information in a custom table and running a cursor over it. The problem as I think you mention is that duplicating this information may lead to stale data, while the sql server metadata is going to be be up to date at all time. to make it easier you could create view over the metadata to make it consumable easily. But that's a different question.

Comment: the columns belong to different tables, and when trying each alter there can be errors like indexes in use, constraints, data would be truncated,etc...so we have to log or correct automatically each alter table separately

Comment: Ok then use this create  list of tables and columns. It's still better to use this list to know what you check.

Comment: The primary question is: what runs faster, check size for mismach and then alter table or alter table directly?

Comment: its a CRM system that manages the user defined tables dinamically...not our choice, the problem is that although in its table for table+columns definitions it says x column is varchar 40, in sql that column is created as varchar(max), this gives problems later...so we have to do an alter table to guarantee the column is defined as varchar(40) in sql

Comment: Being tables created by the CRM system we prefer not to alter them too much. Basing on the part you say that altering a column with a lot of data can be costly we will implement the check before altering each column. As a last question...Doesnt sql detect if the new size is the same as the actual size in an alter table command (as an internal performance optimization)?

Comment: @ase69s - That I don't know. I would like to think that implementers of SQL Server may have done this.